# How do I force python's datetime.strftime to output in UTC?

Tags: python, datetime, time, timezone, strftime

I have two separate machines (local development and server) accessing the same datetime from a database. The datetime objects have the same value (including timezone) on both machines:

**Local**

```
print ts
> datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 13, 7, 18, 9, 209000, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

**Server**

```
print ts
> datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 13, 7, 18, 9, 209000, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

However, the output of `strftime` is different on both machines:

**Local**

```
print ts.strftime('%s')
> 1484320689
```

**Server**

```
print ts.strftime('%s')
> 1484291889
```

What's going on here? How can I get both the client and server to output the same timestamp string in UTC?

Comment: Can you please include the exact way that you create `dt` so that we might replicate properly? Because I would conventionally use `import datetime as dt` which means that `print dt` gives `<module 'datetime' (built-in)>`. Clearly this does not replicate the issue (and is missing the database read), but it's not clear to me how to make an exact test case myself.

Comment: @roganjosh dt was just the name of the variable I obtain from the database. I have renamed it as 'ts' to avoid the confusion with an import such as `import datetime.datetime as dt`.

Comment: You can make a similar test case as follows:

`print datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).strftime('%s')`

Running on the two separate machines will output a different value (more than a few seconds), even if `datetime.utcnow()` is the same on both machines

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this post, I found the solution.

It turns out that strftime always tries to convert to local time and there isn't much you can do about it.

The solution was to use calendar:

```
return calendar.timegm(datetime.utcnow().timetuple())
```

If you need your milliseconds:

```
return calendar.timegm(self.timestamp.timetuple()) * 1000 + self.timestamp.microsecond / 1000
```

Or similar for microseconds.